Why should contributors loose points when a user is removed?
Very recently a user was removed from Christianity Stack Exchange.  This resulted in almost 4,000 points being wiped off the accounts of a lot of contributors.  I was let off light, but one poor soul lost 500 points!
I can understand why some users have their accounts closed, but I can't understand why the contributors whose answers were up-voted by that person, must suffer the consequences of that user being removed.
Can someone please explain why this happens?  I ask because I saw this comment in an old Meta question:

There are a very few occasions where SE has intervened and retained the votes of a user prior to deletion. However, this is rare and only happens when there are several thousand votes at stake and the reputation hit would be unduly severe.

Why are reps removed when a user is removed?

Thanks for posting this, I was thinking of posting a similar Q because a similar thing also happened Oct 2022 when a user who voted a lot deleted his own account.

Agree, it's a worthwhile topic for discussion. Should we only engage with users whom we are very confident will never delete their accounts? (if so, good luck getting engagement with new users) If the site tells people their past contributions aren't valued very much...it discourages future contribution.

What an annoying thought, that if someone deleted their account, they would be wiped away as if they had never existed. Sounds almost like ancient civilization style punishments... even if it isn't a punishment. Weird.

Is there a corollary to "don't put all your eggs in one basket" like "make sure all your eggs aren't from one hen"? I don't know what the rationale is for it, but it's been the norm for years and years.
If the powers that be wanted it to actually be fair (not that it matters that much). They should deduct it proportionally taking into account the points that you put on bounties over the course of the time the person who upvoted your posts was on the site like they would at a store where you returned something that was on sale.
But truly, the whole thing is a counter measure for the real problem of sock puppet voting, so if I make an account just for the purposes of propping up your account and it's later discovered that all my votes are for you, if my account gets destroyed, so do all those votes.

It’s not the removal of the one account that is the problem. It’s the far- reaching effect from more than 100 contributors having (between them) almost 4,000 points wiped off their accounts. I don’t think the person behind the account that was removed was guilty of “sock puppet voting” for more than 100 contributors. If so I would have received lots of votes from this individual but I disagreed with his views. So why should 100 plus contributors be punished because of one bad egg (so as to speak)? Of course the points don't matter because they are not real, although "reputation" might.

I second @Lesley on this.  There is a difference between fraudulent user created specially to upvote dozens of a single user's posts (where removal of ill-gained points would have been good), but in this case and in the Oct 2022 case, the up vote is spread across dozens of users, and those votes reflect the "usefulness" of the post, which if reversed, would make an answer's score negatively impacted when compared to other answers.

I don't think the eggs in one basket analogy works here. None of us has expertise in every topic that's in scope for this site. I answered a lot of questions from this user because he often asked about topics that interest me and about which I have some breadth of knowledge. If the site is working the way it should, people should ask questions on topics that interest them, and people should contribute answers on topics where they have expertise.
